# How to add scope for additional details of GitHub (Sign In) user in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've implemented **GitHub login** for my app using firebase. I'm able to get email, UID and other details for logged in user. But the **DisplayName** is empty.

Can anyone let me know how to get the displayName from GitHub.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all GitHub user profile data immediately after sign-in, via `AdditionalUserInfo`.

Here is an example with the web API:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider())
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Get the GitHub username.
    console.log(userCredential.additionalUserInfo.username);
    // Get GitHub additional user profile.
    console.log(userCredential.additionalUserInfo.profile);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // An error occurred.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my solution if someone needs it and is similar to @bojeli answer.

```
    async gitHubSignIn() {
          let provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();
          this.details = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider); 
    //afAuth is AngularFireAuth
          console.log(this.details.additionalUserInfo.username);
         } 
      }
```